# VBA to hide and show specific pictures in Word header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with locked header and footer that are controlled by a password protected userform, to prevent unauthorised users changing version doc number etc.

I now have a requirement to change the picture in the header depending on the customer, I was hoping to use an option group to enable the authorised person to select the customers logo to use, by making visible the selected and hiding the rest

However I am having trouble addressing each picture individually, they are all formatted as in front of text and via the selection pane I have renamed them to picCustomer1, picCustomer2 etc

I've tried the 3 portions of code below none of which have worked as I expected, as it would in Excel

```
Sub ShowAllPictures()
  Dim nResponse As Integer
 
  nResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to show all pictures?", 4, "Show pictures")
 
  If nResponse = 6 Then
    With ActiveWindow.View
      If .ShowPicturePlaceHolders = True Or .ShowDrawings = False Then
      .ShowPicturePlaceHolders = False
      .ShowDrawings = True
      Else
        MsgBox ("No picture is hidden.")
      End If
    End With
 End If **'doesnt unhide anything**
End Sub
```

```
Sub showhide()
 
  If ActiveDocument.Shapes("picOcado").Visible = False Then **'Item with the specified name not found**
    ActiveDocument.Shapes("picOcado").Visible = True
      Else
    ActiveDocument.Shapes("picOcado").Visible = False
  End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub showhidePic()
 ActiveDocument.InlineShapes("picOcado").Height = 1 **' type mismatch error**
 'ActiveDocument.Shapes("picOcado").Height = 1 **'Item with the specified name not found**
 
End Sub
```

[Selection Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghHjf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate header or footer content, you need to access the HeaderFooter object. Here is sample code that shows how to show a bookmarked inline shape or text, an inline shape and a floating shape:

```
Sub ShowGraphics()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim aSection As Section
  For Each aSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    With aSection
      .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Bookmarks("Disclaimer").Range.Font.Hidden = False  'shows bookmarked range
      .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.InlineShapes(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True  'hides in-line graphics. In-line graphics cannot be named
      .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Shapes("LogoPage1").Visible = True  'shows a named graphic
    End With
  Next aSection
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In the code above, **wdHeaderFooterPrimary** will set the visibility for all headers, unless the documents is set to have a different first page, or different odd and even pages. If the document has a different first page, then **wdHeaderFooterFirstPage** will set the header for the first page while wdHeaderFooterPrimary will set all the following pages.

To process multiple graphics, I would set up a *Select Case* statement. These are easier to read than using many If-Else statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't even think that I'd have to use the HeaderFooter object, one more question though, for InLineShapes how do you identify/reference each shape individually if you can't name them?

Comment: @Lanser FWIW you can give a (persistent) *title* to an InlineShape  but you can't use the Title to index the InlineShapes collection, so you could only find the InlineShape by iterating, and Word doesn't enforce uniqueness of titles either.

Comment: That's why I included the bookmark variation. You can bookmark the inline shape, then refer to it with the bookmark name. You could also set/get the AlternativeText property of the shape if screen reader accessibility is not important: Selection.InlineShapes(1).AlternativeText = GraphicName$